# How To Insert a static object in Vuforia world coordinates without attaching it to an anchor plane or anchor Mid Air Element?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I am facing the following issue :
I need to insert an object in my scene, and I want it to stay in its position,
without moving with the world camera.
can I do that without Palne or Ground Detection?

thanks in advance

Comment: isn't it the default that it stays in position if the camera isn't moving? or maybe I don't understand what you are trying to archieve

Comment: actually, the default behavior, when you put an object in the scene, is to move with the camera, my goal is to insert a static object that doesn't move with the camera ..

Comment: ? no ... the default is that an object stays static in the 3D world so if you move your 3D camera it is staying there and e.g. getting out of your field of view etc. Do you mean you want it allways to be at the same position in the rendered image no matter where and how the camera moves?

Comment: actually, when u are running device tracker and Ground Detection features, when you insert an object dynamically it will move with the camera, and that's what is happening with me ..

Comment: could you show how you insert that object dynamically?

Comment: `Vector3 center = new Vector3(Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2, 1.5f);
Vector3 position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(center);
mainAIROB.transform.position = center;
candle.transform.SetParent(mainAIROB.transform);
candle.transform.position = position;
candle.SetActive(true);`

Comment: mainAIROB is a MidAir static Object 
and the candle is the object i want it to stay in its position when i move the camera

Comment: @derHugo I believe OP is talking about the fact when you place objects without a trackable or without anchoring they tend to move with camera. Also i am afraid you can not do that without Ground plane. Vuforia does not allow you to anchor objects without a trackable as far as i know.